# Can set multiple value in looping the html <p> tag?

Tags: php, html, loops

i want to set value in looping tag

html but i no have idea to do this.

[this is example my code for looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEw6E.png)

```
 <?php
     $show=$alltunjangan->toArray();
     $show2=$allpotongan->toArray();
          for ($i=0; $i<count($alltunjangan); $i++) {
              for ($i=0; $i<count($allpotongan); $i++){
                echo '<tr>
                       <td>  
                       <!-- php concatenation -->                 
                       '.(isset($show[$i]) ? $show[$i]->Nama_Tunjangan:'').'
                       </td>

                       <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
                         <p id="1" class="1"> 0 </p>
                       </td>

                       <td>
                     '.(isset($show2[$i]) ? $show2[$i]->Jenis_Potongan:'').'
                       </td>
                       <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
                         <p id="2" class="2"> 0 </p>
                       </td>
                      </tr>';

                         }
                     }
                  ?>
```

[and this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaG6Q.png)

and then i want to set the value in javascript on click function,

so if the name of tunjangan is tunjangan keluarga, then do something where the value set to tag p and so on..

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Add your html inside your php loop like this

```
<?php
    $show=$a->toArray();
    $show2=$b->toArray();
    for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {

echo '<tr>
            <td>  
           <!-- php concatenation -->                 
              '.(isset($show[$i]) ? $show[$i]->name:'').'

            </td>
            <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
                <p id="1" class="1"> 0 </p>
            </td>'; 
} 

 for ($i=0; $i<count($b); $i++){
       echo'<td>
              '.(isset($show2[$i]) ? $show2[$i]->name2:'').'
            </td>
            <td style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
                <p id="2" class="2"> 0 </p>
            </td>
        </tr>';

       }

   ?>
```

Comment: okay it works, and now i want to set the value at each tag p example : if tunjangan keluarga do some formula and the value set to tag p at row 1 and then if tunjangan anak do some formula and the value set to tag p at row 2..

Comment: i confused to set many value to one tag p with one id and class in many row

Comment: do you need to set the value by a php variable? or something else? if so, tell me your variable name

Comment: yes that's right, but it just produce at row 1, in my case, if i set value to tunjangan keluarga, it will replace at row 1.. and row 2 still 0

Comment: hmm wait a minute i am confused to explain it

Comment: tell me what are your php variables names , this will help to understand the question